# Pass variable as parameter in c++ template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constexpr

I'm trying to implement the follwing function calling:

```
template<int index>
void print() {
    std::cout << index;
}

constexpr int getConstexpr(int a) {
     return a;
}

void function_to_template(int i) {
    const int j = getConstexpr(i);
    print<j>();
}

void main() {
    for(int = 0 ; i < 10; i++) {
       function_to_template(i);
    }
}
```

and I got the following error:

> fatal error: no matching member function for call to 'print'.

any I idea how to pass variable as parameter in c++ template ?

thanks.

Comment: It's simply not possible. Templates is a compile-time *only* construct. Arguments to non-contexpr functions are passed at *run-time* which might happen a long time after compilation.

Comment: why you want to do so?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: your code doesn't works because it's impossible to pass a run-time variable as template parameter

Long answer: the problem is that a `constexpr` function works compile time when can (when the input is know compile time) and must (when the returned vales must to be known compile time as a template value or initializing a `constexpr` value). The compiler can choose to calculate the value compile time also when isn't necessary but can't compile it when isn't known compile time.

So your `constexpr` function

```
constexpr int getConstexpr(int a) {
     return a;
}
```

called in `function_to_template()`

```
void function_to_template(int i) {
    const int j = getConstexpr(i);
    print<j>();
}
```

is computed run-time (not compile-time) because `i` is a run-time value.

If you want to implement a sort of compile time `for`, you should use the standard template tools to make it (starting from C++14) or simulate they (in C++11). I mean: `std::make_integer_sequence` and `std::integer_sequence`

The following is a full compiling example that show what I mean

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <int index>
void print ()
 { std::cout << index; }

template <int ... Is>
void foo (std::integer_sequence<int, Is...> const &)
 { 
   using unused = int[];

   (void)unused { 0, (print<Is>(), 0)... };
 }

int main ()
 {
   foo(std::make_integer_sequence<int, 10>{});
 }
```

Starting from C++17 you can use template folding and simplify `foo()`, avoiding the ugly `unused` part, as follows

```
template <int ... Is>
void foo (std::integer_sequence<int, Is...> const &)
 { (print<Is>(), ...); }
```